# Redirecting Blogger blog.blogspot.com to domain blog.example.com?

Tags: domain-name-system

I am trying to redirect a **Blogger** blog at ***example***.blogspot.com to a domain ***blog.example***.com

I use the following dns entry at *example.com*:

```
blog CNAME ghs.google.com.
```

When accessing blog.example.com the only message I get is:

> ***Forbidden***
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
>
> Apache/2 Server at anothersubdomain.example.com Port 80

However when I look up the *blog.example.com* using an online dns lookup I get

```
N   CNAME   blog.example.com    ghs.google.com
```

What is wrong here?
How long do I need to wait until the new dns record is synchronized in all other dns servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNS can take up to 24 hours to fully propagate everywhere...Is the DNS entry registered someplace major (Network Solutions, etc) or say through your ISP?

Comment: That is what I thought. It is registered using a local hosting provider.